# How can I reset an increment?

Tags: jekyll, liquid

In some template I'm iterating some data using a `for` loop which is part of some other parent `for` loop.

Using some conditions, I need to increment a counter for each iteration of the inner `for` loop, and reset it whenever the template goes to the next outer `for` loop iteration.

I'm using `{% increment someVar %}`, but I can't figure out how to reset `someVar` to `0`.

Is this ever possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `{% assign someVar = 0 %}`, increment with `{% assign someVar = someVar | plus: 1 %}`.

Comment: Yeah I was going to publish an auto-answer to explain this approach, which is the one I'm using after reviewing liquid's docs. Thank you!

Comment: thanks this saved my day. Stupd {% increment var %} why the hell its even implemented if it cannot be reseted ?

Answer (score 2):

The correct way is to use `{% assign someVar = 0 %}` above the loop, and then increment it with `{% assign someVar = someVar | plus: 1 %}`.

I think David's answer just has a typo leading it someVar always being equal to 1, but otherwise was right on the money.

Comment: Thanks, BTW, maybe you could suggest that on his answer and I could be able to edit it and fix the issue ;D

Comment: I wanted to, but I don't have enough reputation :(.